# How to have a non square video inside a video?

Tags: greenscreen

Is there any free software available for green-screening? I prefer Linux, but Windows is also fine.

Comment: Any of the tools mentioned here will do this:
http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12208/what-is-good-software-for-video-editing-under-linux/12209#12209

Comment: The title of this question doesn't really match the question asked in its body.  I recommend that OP change one or the other to clarify.  A circular inset could easily be achieved without chroma keying, for example.

Comment: Any relatively basic non-linear editor should support greenscreen and what is available changes often enough to put this in the realm of a product recommendation question that is better answered by an up to date Google search for products.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your definition of good green screen is.

In terms of free software to do green screen well...Only one that I can even think of that does keying is Da Vinci Lite which is free from blackmagic's website.  It is pretty complex and pro based, but with a little searching around you might find what you want.  I am not sure if you can technically do green screen with it though.

Comment: Yes, Resolve can do this, though I'm not sure if it is suppoted in lite or not.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ma4t5-lFsOE) is a tutorial I found on it with some quick searching.

Comment: Resolve can greenscreen, but it's not made for it.  It doesn't, for instance, have built-in spill suppression or light wrap.  Because it's node based, you can hack your way around these limitations, but it's still quicker to greenscreen with purpose-built apps and plugins.  Also, resolve currently won't export an alpha channel, even in codecs which support alphas.

Comment: you can use OBS which can key. it is livesreaming software so the keyer is meant for face cams, but it should work.

Comment: @JasonConrad I understand its not designed for it, but the OP asked for free applications that are good at it, and I don't think that truly exists

Comment: don't get me wrong.  I'm a huge proponent of Resolve.  I'm just saying, don't expect to get an alpha channel out of it.

Comment: @JasonConrad Absolutely agreed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind learning there is a tool that has them all, green screen, video editing, 3D, compositing...

The name's [Blender](http://www.blender.org)